# Plotting with respect to negative variable

Tags: plotting

I have $\Delta^2 = -t$ defined in Mathematica. If I have a function that contains  $\Delta^2$ dependence, how I can plot with respect to $-t$?

An example would be

$\exp \left(-\frac{\Delta^2 (1-x)^2}{2 \beta ^2}\right)$

Comment: The easiest is probably to just [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) the first equation for $\Delta$ and insert the solution into the expression you want to plot via [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Following is the actual expression: \frac{2 \beta ^3 k \exp \left(-\frac{\Delta ^2 (1-x)^2}{2 \beta ^2}\right) \left(\frac{\left(x^2+(1-x)^2\right) \left(k^2-\Delta  k (1-x) \cos (\theta )\right)}{x^2 (1-x)^2}+\frac{m^2}{x^2 (1-x)^2}\right) \exp \left(\frac{\Delta  k (1-x) \cos (\theta )-k^2}{\beta ^2}\right)}{\pi ^3 \left(16 \pi ^3\right)}.. here you can Integrate this expression over k from 0.00001 to \infty, x from 0.00001 to 0.9, \theta from 0 to 2 \pi and take \beta=0.3659, Plot should be over '-t'